# Changing bits in an int in C?

Tags: c, int, bit

So I have a 16 bit number. Say that the variable name for it is Bits. I want to make it so that Bits[2:0] = 001, 100, and 000, without changing anything else. I'm not sure how to do it, because all I can think of is ORing the bit I want to be a 1 with 1, but I'm not sure how to clear the other bits so that they're 0. If anyone has advice, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: [Shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23)

Comment: First off, it wouldn't be called "Bits", it would be called "bits".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: But wouldn't shift operations change the other bits because it's shifting them? The MSB would change too, unless you do a right arithmetic shift, but then that changes the rest of the number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To clear certain bits, `&` with the inverse of the bits to be cleared. Then you can `|` in the bits you want.

In this case, you want to zero out the lower three bits (`111` in binary or `7` in decimal), so we `&` with `~7` to clear those bits.

```
Bits = (Bits & ~7) | 1; // set lower three bits of Bits to 001
```

Comment: it might help to explain what `~7` is for in case the person asking does not know bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2):

`union` structures allow the ability to specify the number of bits a variable has and address each bit of a bigger variable individually.

```
union {
    short value;
    struct {
        unsigned char bit0 : 1;
        unsigned char bit1 : 1;
        unsigned char bit2 : 1;
        unsigned char bit3 : 1;
        unsigned char bit4 : 1;
        unsigned char bit5 : 1;
        unsigned char bit6 : 1;
        unsigned char bit7 : 1;
        unsigned char bit8 : 1;
        unsigned char bit9 : 1;
        unsigned char bit10 : 1;
        unsigned char bit11 : 1;
        unsigned char bit12 : 1;
        unsigned char bit13 : 1;
        unsigned char bit14 : 1;
        unsigned char bit15 : 1;
    } bits;
} var;
```

Now you have a variable named `var` that hold a 16-bit integer which can be referenced by `var.value`, and you have access to each individual bit of this variable by acessing `var.bits.bit0` through `var.bits.bit15`.

By setting `var.value = 0;` all bits are set to 0 too. By setting `var.bits.bit0 = 1;` you automatically change the value of `var.value` to `0x8000`, or as seen in binary, `1000000000000000`.

If you intention is change only the 3 last bits, you can simplify the structure to something more like this:

```
union {
    short value;
    struct {
        unsigned short header : 13;
        unsigned char bit13 : 1;
        unsigned char bit14 : 1;
        unsigned char bit15 : 1;
    } bits;
} var;
```

Now you have the `var.bits.header`, that is a 13-bits variable, and 3 other 1-bit variables you can play with.

But notice C++ does not support this kind of structure, so for best C to C++ portability you might prefer to use [bitwise operations](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html) instead as proposed by @nneonneo.