# C - Method for setting all even-numbered bits to 1

Tags: c, bit

I was charged with the task of writing a method that "returns the word with all even-numbered bits set to 1." Being completely new to C this seems really confusing and unclear. I don't understand how I can change the bits of a number with C. That seems like a very low level instruction, and I don't even know how I would do that in Java (my first language)! Can someone please help me! This is the method signature.

```
int evenBits(void){
    return 0;
}
```

Any instruction on how to do this or even guidance on how to **begin** doing this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing bits in an int in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915198/changing-bits-in-an-int-in-c)

Comment: Wikipedia's [Bitwise Operations in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) could help.

Comment: First of all you should ask the auhor, what the `word` is in C.

Comment: Using hex to get the number you need to set 2, 4, .... (i.e. 0x66666666).  Answer is return this number. You do not need the `void`

Comment: @EdHeal - Yes, he should use the `void` if this is C and the function takes no arguments.  `int evenBits()` has a very different meaning.

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_

Comment: if you use the bitwise or operator and do an assignment, you turn the indicated bit on.  For example, x = x | 1; will turn on the low order bit.  You just need to repeatedly call the operator for the correct bit positions.

Comment: Why operators? It's as simple as `return 0x55555555`, if we start counting bits at zero, or do I miss something?

Comment: Numbers in C is mostly 0 based, so I don't know whether you want `0x55555555U` or `0xaaaaaaaaU`

Comment: Well, we've had 6's and 5's.  I vote for 0xAAAAAAAA as the mask

Comment: You are all at sixes and sevens :)

Comment: One could also say `0` is neither an odd nor an even number, so `0x55555554` ?

Comment: Is `bit 0` the MSB (POWER) or LSB (virtually every other architecture)?

Comment: @MartinJames that's a bit odd.

Comment: .. and which bit is bit 2, ie. even?

Comment: 5's or A's?  Depends on OP - could go either way: the odds are evens.

Comment: The first bit is bit 0 but although it codes `1` it is even numbered. The next m.s. bit is bit 1 which holds `2` which is even but the bit is odd. The next m.s. bit represents `4` and that is bit 2 but thankfully both the bit number and its coded value are even, so we can relax.

Comment: Well, I'm glad that's all cleared up!

Comment: @WeatherVane: On POWER, bit 0 is the MSB.

Comment: @EOF please kill me if I ever get a job using such an architecture:(

Comment: Surely bit 1 (the first bit) is 0-1, second (and the first even bit) is 0 -2...

Comment: @EOF and `#define CHAR_BIT 9` is the [baker's dozen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dozen#Baker.27s_dozen)

Comment: I WIN!  '(2) How do I find out the representation of "all even-numbered bits"' .... OP: 'I know the answer to (2), it's 2863311530' - that's 0xAAAAAAAA \o/  \o/

Comment: LOL, sometimes I just love SO...

Comment: If it wasn't obviously a homework dump, I'd put the A's as an answer and demand my prize!

Comment: Actually, in an "exact words" reading of the question, I'd `return (unsigned)-1;`

Comment: @EOF 0xFOFF - I want my prize!

Comment: TBH, that's the best fun I've had on SO for a week.  I'm in such a good mood now that I'm not going to look at any more questions tonite, (since that would surely spoil it).   Beer time:)

Comment: @MartinJames: No, `0xF0FF` does not constitute a valid answer. Why would you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down into two problems.

*(1) Given a variable, how do I set particular bits?*

Hint: use a bitwise operator.

*(2) How do I find out the representation of "all even-numbered bits" so I can use a bitwise operator to set them?*

Hint: Use math. ;-) You could make a table (or find one) such as:

```
Decimal | Binary
--------+-------
      0 | 0
      1 | 1
      2 | 10
      3 | 11
    ... | ...
```

Once you know what operation to use to set particular bits, and you know a decimal (or hexadecimal) integer literal to use that with in C, you've solved the problem.

Comment: I know the answer to (2), it's 2863311530. But I'm not sure how to do (1). If I get any random number like 1000111010, how would I change that number to 2863311530 with only these operations: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>?

Comment: @lovethehelp we're not here to do your assignment for you; we expect that you can research that on your own. Take a look at what happens to a number when each binary operator is used. What is the effect on the output? For example, `0 & 0 == 0, 1 & 0 == 0, 0 & 1 == 0, 1 & 1 == 1`. Could the `&` operator be used to set bits? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: @lovethehelp is the `=` forbidden? You can change that number to 2863311530 with `=`. "Even" with that list of operators, you'll need the `=` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You must give a precise definition of *all even numbered bits*. Bits are numbered in different ways on different architectures. Hardware people like to number them from `1` to `32` from the least significant to the most significant bit, or sometimes the other way, from the most significant to the least significant bit... while software guys like to number bits by increasing order starting at `0` because bit `0` represents the number 2<sup>0</sup>, ie: 1.

With this latter numbering system, the bit pattern would be `0101...0101`, thus a value in hex `0x555...555`.  If you number bits starting at 1 for the least significant bit, the pattern would be `1010...1010`, in hex `0xAAA...AAA`. But this representation actually encodes a negative value on current architectures.

I shall assume for the rest of this answer that even numbered bits are those representing even powers of 2: `1` (2<sup>0</sup>), `4` (2<sup>2</sup>), `16` (2<sup>4</sup>)...

The short answer for this problem is:

```
int evenBits(void) {
    return 0x55555555;
}
```

But what if `int` has 64 bits?

```
int evenBits(void) {
    return 0x5555555555555555;
}
```

Would handle 64 bit `int` but would have implementation defined behavior on systems where `int` is smaller.

Using macros from `<limits.h>`, you could mask off the extra bits to handle 16, 32 and 64 bit ints:

```
#include <limits.h>

int evenBits(void) { 
    return 0x5555555555555555 & INT_MAX;
}
```

But this code still makes some assumptions:

- `int` has at most 64 bits.
- `int` has an even number of bits.
- `INT_MAX` is a power of 2 minus 1.

These assumptions are valid for most current systems, but the C Standard allows for implementations where one or more are invalid.

Comment: Another assumption is that you can present the constant 0x5555555555555555 at all

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: that's correct, I added a paragraph to confirm this.  The initial discussion in the answer explains why the question is imprecise.

Comment: hmm I guess C11 requires support for long long that is at least 64 bits, but not all compilers are up-to-date

Comment: There's a way that satisfies all numbering systems (LSB == bit 0, LSB == bit 1, MSB == Bit 0 (POWER)). The question leaves the state of the odd bits unspecified, so a result of all ones `(unsigned)-1` / `0xFFFFFFFF` is a valid answer...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: yes I do assume C99 or later. Not all compilers are up-to-date with a 17 year old standard, supporting every non standard compiler would be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @EOF: Technically correct, you get the prize for abusing the rules. But converting `0xFFFFFFFF` to 32 bit `int` produces an implementation defined result, the same for `(unsigned)-1` converted back to `int` per the function signature, and `-1` would not qualify if the architecture uses sign+magnitude representation for integers.

Comment: @chqrlie: Hmm, right. You'd need something like `int retval; unsigned minusone = -1; memcpy(&retval, &minusone, sizeof(int)); return retval;`

Comment: @EOF: I'm afraid you may have stored a trap value into `retval`, returning this value would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie: Sure. I'm not sure there's a way to avoid that though, since `int` may also contain padding bits, setting any number of even bits to one is probably implementation-defined at best. The sane way around this is to only use unsigned types for bit-twiddling.

Answer (score 0):

So basically every other bit has to be set to one? This is why we have bitwise operations in C. Imagine a regular bitarray. What you want is the right most even bit and set it to 1(this is the number 2). Then we just use the OR operator (|) to modify our existing number. After doing that. we bitshift the number 2 places to the left (<< 2), this modifies the bit array to 1000 compared to the previous 0010. Then we do the same again and use the or operator. The code below describes it better.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char SetAllEvenBitsToOne(unsigned char x);
int IsAllEvenBitsOne(unsigned char x);

int main()
{
    unsigned char x = 0; //char is one byte data type ie. 8 bits.

    x = SetAllEvenBitsToOne(x);
    int check = IsAllEvenBitsOne(x);
    if(check==1)
    {
        printf("shit works");
    }

    return 0;
}

unsigned char SetAllEvenBitsToOne(unsigned char x)
{
    int i=0;
    unsigned char y = 2;
    for(i=0; i < sizeof(char)*8/2; i++)
    {
        x = x | y;
        y = y << 2;
    }
    return x;
}

int IsAllEvenBitsOne(unsigned char x)
{
    unsigned char y;
    for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(char)*8/2); i++)
        {

            y = x >> 7;
            if(y > 0)
            {
                printf("x before: %d\t", x);
                x = x << 2;
                printf("x after: %d\n", x);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not all even bits are 1\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        printf("All even bits are 1\n");
        return 1;
}
```

Here is a link to [Bitwise Operations in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)